# Run Command in Php without wait in browser in Windows

Tags: php, windows, command, command-prompt

I followed many of ways in windows to make a command run without interrupting browser. Whenever I try to:

```
exec("ping 8.8.8.8")
```

it makes browser to wait for process to complete.

After completion of process it echoes the output.So what i want is to run a command(like ping) without interrupting browser and store output in variable.

In my case I want to show a dialogue until ping is over and show output afterwards.

I tried:

```
exec(start \B myexecutable.exe)
```

without success.Also tried

```
pclose(popen(start \B myexecutable.exe))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you may want to try http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php `Note: This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode. `

Comment: PHP doesn't work that way. You can't load something in the browser and then send it something else from the same PHP execution.

The more sensible thing to do would be to make an AJAX request on page load, then remove the dialogue and show the output when you get a response.

Comment: as mentioned above, ajax is the way forward if you want the page to be available and just wait for a response.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late answer but for me this works on Windows & Linux:

```
if (isWindows()) {
    pclose(popen("start /B php myfile.php -args", 'r'));
} else {
    exec("php myfile.php -args");
}
```

You need to activate the php directive

```
ignore_user_abort(true)
```